# fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y

Tags: logistic-regression

I receive the following error;

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-d2877618fb0b> in <module>()
      3   if cleaned_df[column].dtype == np.number:
      4     continue
----> 5   cleaned_df[column] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(cleaned_df[column])

TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

My Code is as follows:

```
for column in cleaned_df.columns:
  if cleaned_df[column].dtype == np.number:
    continue
  cleaned_df[column] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(cleaned_df[column])
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add paranthesis after `LabelEncoder`:

```
cleaned_df[column] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(cleaned_df[column])
```

Answer (score 1):

u are missing add () after LabelEncoder.
try this :
`le=LabelEncoder()  for column in cleaned_df.columns:  if cleaned_df[column].dtype == np.number:  continue  cleaned_df[column] = le.fit_transform(cleaned_df[column])`