# first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to save the new CSV file by dropping some values and changing the DateTime format little help... I had few errors but now it's...first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
data1 = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
data1['date']= data1.datetime.apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])
data1['hour']= data1.datetime.apply(lambda x : x.split()[1].split(":")[0])
data1["weekday"]= data1.date.apply(lambda dateString : calendar.day_name[datetime.strptime(dateString,"%m/%d/%Y").weekday()])
data1["month"]= data1.date.apply(lambda dateString : calendar.month_name[datetime.strptime(dateString,"%m/%d/%Y").month])
data1.to_csv("output1.csv")
bookings = data1.groupby('month')['Total_booking'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
bookings.to_csv("output2.csv")
from pandas import get_dummies
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
data1['holiday'] =  le.fit_transform(data1['holiday'])

newdata = pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['weekday','month','season','weather'])
data2 = pd.concat(newdata,axis=1)

newdata1 = data1.drop(['weekday','month','season','weather'],axis=1,inplace=true)
newdata1.to_csv('output/output3.csv')
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1496/4131473043.py in <module>
   5 
   6 newdata = pd.get_dummies(data1,columns=['weekday','month','season','weather'])
   ----> 7 data2 = pd.concat(newdata,axis=1)
  8 
  9 newdata1 = data1.drop(['weekday','month','season','weather'],axis=1,inplace=true)

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in 
       wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
       309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
     310                 )
    --> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
      312 
      313         return wrapper

       ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py 
       in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, 
       names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
       292     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
        293     """
       --> 294     op = _Concatenator(
        295         objs,
        296         axis=axis,

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in 
   __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, 
 ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
      327     ):
       328         if isinstance(objs, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame, str)):
       --> 329             raise TypeError(
         330                 "first argument must be an iterable of pandas "
          331                 f'objects, you passed an object of type "{type(objs).__name__}"'

        TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Comment: The error shown in your traceback suggests that you did not import `get_dummies` from pandas correctly. Either do `import pandas as pd` and then `pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['weekday','month','season','weather'])` or `from pandas import get_dummies` and then as in your code snippet.

Comment: Although the error in your traceback does not match the title of the question, so maybe there is something missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fit\_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612504/fit-transform-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y)

Answer (score 1):

When concatenating dataframes -`pd.concat()` expects a **list of dataframes**, so if `df1` and `df2` are two dataframes - then you implement as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],ignore_index=True)
```

If you do not provide this **list** - then you can get the error :

`first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type DataFrame`

i.e. `pd.concat(df1, df2)` will generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the concat() function.
In pd.concat function the input should be multiple dataframes for example, and the function will concatenate them (Thus, first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects) so that the function can combine them into one pandas object (into one dataframe for example).

I am speculating but if you are trying to get a logical and of all the columns in the dataframe you can do something like:

```
df.all(axis=1)
```